# Change of constraint's constant is laggy while using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the code:

```
@objc func handleSwipe(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        let c = self.cardView.frontCardConstraint.constant - translation.y
        if c < 35 && c >= 11 {
            self.cardView.frontCardConstraint.constant = c
            self.cardView.layoutIfNeeded()
        } else {
            //
        }
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        //
    }
    sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

It does what I want, but when dragging fast it appears quite laggy. Is there anything I could change or should I switch to a custom gesture recognizer?

Comment: what is the `frontCardConstraint`? what are you trying to do with the card?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. So I have two cards, one behind the other. `frontCardConstraint` is the bottom constraint for the front card. I want it to move vertically using the gesture recognizer, and when it is dragged enough (the constant is bigger than 35) I want the cards to switch order (the cut code in the else statement).

Comment: what do you mean by lagging ?? shaking fastly ????

Comment: I mean, when the card is dragged fast, the "animation" stutters a bit.

Comment: Two considerations: 1. Is the drawing of the card complicated (e.g. a high resolution image that you've scaled down to fix the card view; dynamically drawing anything in `draw(_:)`; use of shadows or transparencies; etc.). 2. you might want to use touch events rather gesture recognizer so that you can use predictive touches to reduce perceived lagginess.

Comment: 1: no, it’s just an image from an UIColor, and 2: I’ll try it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `transform` property instead of changing the constraint (I guess layout calculation might be inefficient).

Just small changes in your code are needed. First calculate `c` using this:

```
let c = self.cardView.transform.ty - translation.y
```

And then move the `cardView` by replacing:

```
self.cardView.frontCardConstraint.constant = c
self.cardView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

with this:

```
self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: c, y: 0)
```

When you finish the panning, just set `self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity` to reset it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, now it’s even laggier :(

Comment: @Dimitrie-TomaFurdui I didn't see that coming.. could you share a working example that we could try ourselves?

Comment: You mean, the project?

Comment: @Dimitrie-TomaFurdui if you can share the whole project (in case it's not under confidentiality), that's an option too.. or a minimal example on which we can replicate your issues (so just the relevant part of project base).. but a working example taht we can either open as a project, or copy paste to playground

Comment: Will it help if I share a screenshot of the XIB?